# Quitting vim issue

Tags: git, vim

I tried git pulling some stuff and after that I haven't been able to quit vim even after pressing the Escape key, then the colon key ":" and after that "q".
Can someone please help me in quitting vim?

[image]

Comment: If you want to quit emacs like it's vi: `esc-x vip-mode`, then `:q!` But it's still emacs : - )

Comment: @Dhruv, were you able to quit the editor?

Answer (score 13):

You are running emacs - quit using Ctrl-X Ctrl-C.